# Json parsing in Scala with scala.util.parsing.json

Tags: json, scala

I have a json object `"{"id":1,"name":"OZKA","birthDate":"1981-02-08T20:00:00.000Z","monthRevenue":1000.75,"developer":true}"` and the code:

```
println(request.getParameter("content"))//{"id":1,"name":"OZKA","birthDate":"1981-02-08T20:00:00.000Z","monthRevenue":1000.75,"developer":true}
val result = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(request.getParameter("content"))
result match {
  case Some(e) => { println(e); //output: Map(name -> OZKA, monthRevenue -> 1000.75, developer -> true, birthDate -> 1981-02-08T20:00:00.000Z, id -> 1.0)
    e.foreach((key: Any, value: Any) => {println(key + ":" + value)})
  }
  case None => println("Failed.")
}
```

, when I try to call map or foreach function, compiler throws an error "value foreach is not a member of Any". Can anybody suggest me a way, how i can parse this json string and convert its to Scala types

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error that you get is caused because the compiler has no way of knowing the type of `e` in `Some(e)` pattern, its infered as `Any`. And `Any` doesnt have a `foreach` method. You can solve this by explicitly specifying the type of `e` as a `Map`.

Secondly, for a Map `foreach` has the signature `foreach(f: ((A, B)) ⇒ Unit): Unit`. The argument of the anonymous function is a tuple containing the key and value.

Try something like this:

```
println(request.getParameter("content"))//{"id":1,"name":"OZKA","birthDate":"1981-02-08T20:00:00.000Z","monthRevenue":1000.75,"developer":true}
val result = scala.util.parsing.json.JSON.parseFull(request.getParameter("content"))
result match {
  case Some(e:Map[String,String]) => {
    println(e); //output: Map(name -> OZKA, monthRevenue -> 1000.75, developer -> true, birthDate -> 1981-02-08T20:00:00.000Z, id -> 1.0)
    e.foreach { pair =>
        println(pair._1 + ":" + pair._2)        
    }
  }
  case None => println("Failed.")
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, it's working!  `e.foreach { pair: Tuple2 [String,String] =>
          println(pair._1 + ":" + pair._2)
        }
      }`

Comment: I used the same pattern, to catch parsing failure but the compiler returned the following warnings: "non-variable type argument String in type pattern Map[String,String] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure"

Answer (score 3):

you may access keys and values in any json as:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json.JSON
import scala.collection.immutable.Map

val jsonMap = JSON.parseFull(response).getOrElse(0).asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
val innerMap = jsonMap("result").asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
innerMap.keys //will give keys
innerMap("anykey") //will give value for any key anykey
```